# change portlet mode programmatically in controller

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'm trying to write a Liferay MVC controller and I want to change the portlet mode in my renderer method.
The `RenderRequest` object does have a `_portletMode` property but there are no setter methods for that.

Note that I don't want to use java reflection to set that property because I'm concerned that it may affects something I'm not aware of!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change portlet state (or mode) in the rander phase. Even if you can trick around, it's nonstandard, not supported for a reason.

You can however just display some other UI (e.g. jsp) during your render phase.

Changing state always involves one of the other phases.

Comment: Would you tell me when and how I'm allowed to change portlet mode. Thanx.

Comment: What do you want to use the portlet mode for? I'm asking because I most frequently see it used wrong - and it wouldn't make sense to explain it for a wrong usecase. Related, you can change the portlet mode during the action- event- or resource phases, just not in the render phase. `response.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);` is what you call in order to switch to another (VIEW in this case) portlet mode. Just add that line to your action handler (for example)